# Input Type="date" doesn't work in IE

Tags: html, browser

Why does the type="date" work in Chrome but not IE:

```
<input name="start_date" type="date" value="<?php echo $today;?>" autocomplete="off" required="required">
```

If you need more information let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: This is not supported by IE.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Here you can see what is compatible when it comes to input types http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Comment: @PederN http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @PederN they get alot of stuff right, but they aren't affiliated with w3c, and do get things incorrect.

Comment: it's IE. What did you expect? :D

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler I wish I could give you a million upvotes for that

Answer (score 11):

input type='date' is an HTML 5 feature.  As such, it is not implemented by all browsers yet, and will not be supported by older browsers like IE 7 and 8.

http://caniuse.com/#search=date

You should use a polyfill with javascript to handle these cases and provide a consistent user experience on browsers that dont support HTML5.

Comment: Or IE11, as is evidenced by the caniuse link in the answer.  In fact, most browsers seem to not implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You can test, which elements of new HTML5 standard are supported by which browser by just opening site like http://html5test.com/ in your browser